# Prove that if $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers, then $a < b$ if and only if $a^2 < b^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Where the natural numbers are defined as the positive integers.

My attempt at a proof:

Assume $a < b$. Then there exists a natural number $x$ such that $a + x = b$.

$(a + x)^2 = b^2$

$a^2 + (2ax + x^2) = b^2$

Since $(2ax + x^2)$ is a natural number, $a^2 < b^2$.

Is this correct? Does my proof satisfy the iff part?

Comment: Your proof as it is might not work, but if I'm not mistaken, law of trichotomy may work here by showing a>b and a=b is impossible.

Comment: If you want to prove $A\iff B$ ($A$ iff $B$) then you must prove both $A\implies B$ and $B\implies A$. The latter implication is the same as $A\Longleftarrow B$, so you can see where the iff symbol comes from hopefully. These types of result are strong in the sense that they show  $A$ and $B$, whatever they are, to be equivalent.

Comment: Your proof is correct for $a<b\implies a^2<b^2$. It doesn't prove the reverse direction.

Answer (score 4):

> Does my proof satisfy the iff part?

No, it does not. From $a^2<b^2$ you can only deduce that $b^2=a^2+x$ for some natural $x$. It isn't clear how to deduce from that that $x$ has to be of the form $2ax+x^2$ (in order to use the short multiplication formula). Another problem is the implication

$$(a+x)^2=b^2\ \Rightarrow\ a+x=b$$

While true in naturals you would have to give a proof.

---

So here's an easier approach.

Since $0<a$, $0<b$ and $a<b$ then

$$a^2=aa<ab<bb=b^2$$

The other implication is actually very easy. Assume that $a^2<b^2$ and assume that $b\leq a$ (note that the order on naturals is total). If $b=a$ then obviously $a^2=b^2$. If $b<a$ then the first part implies that $b^2<a^2$. Both lead to contradiction. Hence the only possibility is $a<b$.

Note that the assumption that $a,b$ are naturals is not needed. It is enough if both are positive reals.

Answer (score 0):

write $$a^2<b^2$$ as $$0<(b-a)(b+a)$$

Comment: That already presupposes that $b-a\in\mathbb N$ and therefore only works for one direction.

Comment: in the other direction you can assume that $$a\geq b$$ and from here you will get a contradiction

Answer (score 0):

You have shown (correctly), that $a<b$ implies $a^2<b^2$.

It remains to show that $a^2<b^2$ implies $a<b$.

To this end show that $b^2-a^2>0$ implies $b>a$. Observe that $b^2-a^2=(b-a)(b+a)$.

Can you take it from here ?

Comment: If you don't already know that $a<b$, then you cannot know that $b^2-a^2$ can be factored (in $\mathbb N$!) as $(b-a)(b+a)$.

Comment: @celtschk Who says that the factorization need to be in $\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 0):

We have to prove two things:

- $a < b \implies a^2 < b^2$, and,
- $a^2< b^2 \implies a<b$.

For the first part, note that: $$ \begin{align} a< b \implies a^2 < ab \\ \implies ab < b^2 \\ \implies a^2< b^2 \end{align}$$

For the second part, note that: $$\begin{align} a^2< b^2 \implies a^2-b^2<0 \\ \implies (a-b)(a+b) < 0\end{align}$$ and since $(a+b) > 0$, we have: $$(a-b) < 0 \implies a< b$$

The two parts done!

Comment: If $a^2<b^2$ then **in $\mathbb N$** $a^2-b^2$ is not defined.There does not exist an $n\in\mathbb N$ with $n<0$.

Comment: @celtschk But, who said factorisation should also be be in $\mathbb{N}$? Definitely $9<16 \implies 9-16<0$, right? Or, am I wrong??

Comment: If you are using an embedding of $\mathbb N$ in a larger set (such as $\mathbb Z$), you have to explicitly have to say so. And of course that presupposes that you *already constructed* that larger set (and should you anywhere have used the fact you're trying to prove in the construction of $\mathbb Z$, your proof will be circular).